# Does IBM BlueMix's Push Notifications service provide a console for authoring messages?

Tags: push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

Not finding anything here:

```
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/index.html
```

I'm looking for a web console for sending messages to apps - similar to what is offered by UrbanAirship and Parse (rest its soul).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the IBM Push Notification service has a Push Dashboard where you can author messages, customize the notification payload, specify the target audience and send notifications to both iOS and Android in both Production and Sandbox modes.

Here's a screenshot of the Push Dashboard: [image]

The docs go into it a bit here: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/enablepush_ios.html#t_push_send

To access it you'll just need to create a Bluemix application using the MobileFirst Services Starter Boilerplate, and then navigate to the IBM Push Notifications instance from your application dashboard at which point you will be prompted to provide your .p12 certificate and/or GCM credentials.